# Alterar cor de fundo de um item selecionado no listview de um menu em uma Master Detail Page com Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Quando seleciono um item no menu, ele fica com uma cor de fundo predefinido pelo Xamarin, mas gostaria de mudar essa cor.

Estou usando um MasterDetailPage no Xamarin.Forms

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá uma conferida nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885238/xamarin-forms-listview-set-the-highlight-color-of-a-tapped-item